# datatables Cannot reinitialise DataTable and destroy is not working

Tags: javascript, datatable

I have tried all the commands for destroy and empty of the datatable after selecting a new option, and is not working.

this is some part of my js file that contains the ajax. it uses dynamic urls apis.

```
    function table(url, columns) {
    
        var dt = $("#datatables").dataTable({
            "serverSide": true,
            "processing": true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": url,
                "type": "GET",
            },
            "columns": columns,
            lengthMenu: [[25, 100, 250, 500], [25, 100, 250, 500]],
            pageLength: 25,
            // destroy: true
        });
    ... // more stuff here about the design of the table
    }

    $("form#btnGetDomain").on("submit", function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        ev.stopPropagation();

        // $("#datatables").dataTable().fnDestroy();

        var url;
        var columns;
    
        var categ = document.getElementById("categ").value;

    // this is where i do if statements depending what options was selected
// i get the proper url api
    ... 
    
        table(url, columns);
    });
```

i have tried all those commands:

```
$("#datatables").dataTable().fnDestroy();

$("#datatables").empty();


destroy: true,
```

The command **"destroy: true"**  inside the dataTable i don't know if it works properly because after i try to select the second time another option, the table doesn't responde, it just says ** Processing....**

I also tried to put the comand inside the on submit function before i select any option to clear the table. Now i m thinking of doing an if statement, if their is a table, clear it.

Thank you

**UPDATE**

i ve tried with **dataTable** and **DataTable**

**UPDATE 2 **

```
if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable("#datatables")) {
        $("#datatables").DataTable().clear().draw();
        $("#datatables").dataTable().fnDestroy();
    }
```

This command i have put before the **var dt = $("#datatables").dataTable({...**

Yes i noticed i used small and big cap datatable...but this worked ...i did try to put both with big **D** but didn't work... also tryed to use in the last one:  DataTable().destroy();...didn't work

Example: using videos and channels
I have selected the first time videos.

After i select channels:
It changes the columns names no problem ( i have different columns names for every api)... but the rows remain the same.

When i select back to videos.
Column names change, and rows are changing to previous selection which was channels.

Hope you can understand. It doesn't really make sense why i have to use **dataTable** and **DataTable**...

it does change, but wrong changes...at least i am getting closer to the answer, hopefully.

Answer (score 3):

I found out the answer i put this lines of code at the beginning of the **table function**

```
function table(url, columns) {
    var dt;

    if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable("#datatables")) {
        $("#datatables").DataTable().clear().draw();
        $("#datatables").DataTable().destroy();
        $("#datatables thead").html('');
    }

...
}
```

It works for me fine, it clears the rows, destroys the table, and empty the **thead**.

Oh..and i have change from lower case **dataTable** too upper case **DataTable**

Comment: the solution is working for me.
if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable("#routerInfoTable")) {
    $("#routerInfoTable").DataTable().clear().draw();
    $("#routerInfoTable").DataTable().destroy();
    $("#routerInfoTable").html(html);
    $("#routerInfoTable").DataTable();
 } else {
     $("#routerInfoTable").html(html);
     $("#routerInfoTable").DataTable();
  }

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: Did you try clear command? https://datatables.net/reference/api/clear()

```
$('#datatables').DataTable().clear().draw();
```

Another thing you could try is using the variable to destroy the table:

```
var dt = $('#datatables').DataTable({...init stuff...});
dt.destroy();
```

---

This could be a dt version issue. Did you try:

```
$('#datatables').DataTable().destroy();
```

Please notice the difference dataTable vs DataTable.

Comment: yup, i ve tried with **dataTable** and **DataTable**...and i also tried tried that command, in both function

Comment: i have tried something close to what you gave me.. i will update at the end the question...something weird is going on with the table